# NoneType object has no attribute get

Tags: python, tkinter, numerical-methods, nonetype

I've got in a bit of trouble while working with tkinter
The problem is that there are no methods which can work with widget Text. Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
tex = Text(root, width = 50, height = 10, bd = 2).pack()
tex.get(1.0, END)
root.mainloop()
```

It returns error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

it makes me mad! and I have such problems with any Text's methods

Comment: A duplicate exists with all of the words in this question's title. Please search stackoverflow for answers before posting new questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You save the return value of "pack" in "tex", which is None.
This is correct:

```
tex = Text(root, width = 50, height = 10, bd = 2)
tex.pack()
```